# C# error : CS0103 The name ' ' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, class, methods

I'm trying to call a class object made in the `Main` in a method outside of the `Main`, but it is not working. I'm new to C# so I am used to python's Def and its way different.

```
public class User
{
  public string name;
  public string password;
  public string notepad;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------\n"+"Please create a new user."+"\n--------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("\nUsername: ");
    string x = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("\nPassword: ");
    string y = Console.ReadLine();
    **User xe = new User();
    xe.name = x;**

   ----removed cuz has nothing to do with the code----

    Console.WriteLine("Dashboard");
    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease choose a function by inputting the number before the name.\n1 - Notepad\n2 - Calculator");

    while(login) {
        try{
            int letter = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            login = false;
            if(letter == 1) {
                Console.WriteLine("Notepad");
            }
            else if(letter == 2) {
                Console.WriteLine("Calculator");
            }
        }
        catch{
            Console.WriteLine("Please input a number.");
        }
    }
}
**public static string notepad(string np){
    np = Console.ReadLine();
    xe.notepad = np;**
}
```

I put ** on the parts that are giving an error.

Comment: Your `notepad` method does not return any value but its siganture suggests it should return a `string`. Add a `return` statement in it.

Comment: *"I put ** on the parts that are giving an error."* - You've indicated multiple parts of the code.  Which one are you asking about?  What is the exact error?  What exact line does the error refer to?  Please format the code as complete and compile-able code (aside from the compilation error in question of course), you can use a comment on the target line to indicate which one it is.

Comment: If I were to *guess* the error you're referring to... You're trying to reference a variable called `xe` in your `notepad` method, but that method has no such variable.

Comment: Yeah its kinda confusing, I'm trying to have xe into the notepad method, basically trying to call a class into another method? I don't know if thats how you say it.

Comment: Your notepad method is trying to use an object (xe) which is out of scope. You would have to pass the xe to the notepad method so that it can act on it. Curious, why would you have a param (string np) for the notepad method, if you're only going to ask for it (np) from the user, once you're inside the method?

Comment: How could I pass it inside? I am new to C# and not familiar with anything haha, in python you don't need to do any of that and it has a `global` function that makes variables accessible from outside classes.

I am not sure about the np part, I have tried to make another method, for a calculator. It seems to work for now...

Comment: You should do some reading on scope of variables

Comment: In your code you weren't using global variable. You are using a local variable (xe) and trying to treat it globally.

Comment: How could you treat it globally, I searched how to do it but its super confusing...

Comment: I should have said, and you are trying to treat it as if it had global scope. If you want to use it globally, you would have to define it in a global space in the class which is outside of the methods in the class. That way all the methods in the class have access to it.

Comment: ah, I see. So outside of the default "Program" class?

Comment: Yes. As long as it's in the namespace.

Comment: As @bradbury9 mentioned, you should read up on scope to avoid vulnerabilities in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code below.
I've commented the areas that I've modified.
There were a few areas of concern. Most noticeably, you never called the notepad method.
Also, the combined input request (convert(getinput)) kept crashing. So, I broke it up into two lines.

Since you weren't returning anything from the notepad method, I changed the return type to void. Then, I changed the method signature from notepad(string np) to notepad(User xel). This passes the xe object to the notepad method.

I've added some writelines to show where you are in the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class User
    {
        public string name;
        public string password;
        public string notepad;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // I've added this line to get around the missing login source
            bool login = true;

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\n--------------------------\n" + "Please create a new user." + "\n--------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\nUsername: ");
            string x = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\nPassword: ");
            string y = Console.ReadLine();
            User xe = new User();
            xe.name = x;

            //----removed cuz has nothing to do with the code----

            Console.WriteLine("Dashboard");
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease choose a function by inputting the number before the name.\n1 - Notepad\n2 - Calculator");

            while (login)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Here I've separated the input request, the combination of the convertion and the input mixed kept crashing.
                    string theletter = Console.ReadLine();
                    int letter = Convert.ToInt32(theletter);

                    login = false;
                    if (letter == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Notepad");

                        // Here I'm calling the notepad method with the xe
                        notepad(xe);
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n* Ok, I'm back in the Main *\n");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else if (letter == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Calculator");
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please input a number.");
                }
            }
        }

        // **** Here I've changed the return type from string to void, since it's not returning anything.
        // **** I've also added a parameter to pass the xe as xel (optional) using the proper type
        public static void notepad(User xel)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n * I'm here in the notepad method *\n");
            string np = Console.ReadLine();
            xel.notepad = np;
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou entered this for your notepad: \n");
            Console.WriteLine(np);
            Console.WriteLine("\nThis is your new notepad: \n");
            Console.WriteLine(xel.notepad);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So since you added xel would this be a different user than the xe from the class? Sorry I'm such a noob at this.

Comment: xel was a name I made up for the parameter in the signature. It holds the object of that type when it's passed. xel is a copy of the xe object. If you want to persist it, you would have to return it.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(np.ToString());` ??? You should either `Console.WriteLine(np);` or `Console.WriteLine(xel.notepad);`

Comment: I did them both, so that you could see that the values were properly passed. But you don't have to.

Comment: Oh, you were referring to the .ToString() part. That's just a habit I have since I use visual studio a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the variable `xe` from the method `notepad` because it is from the method `Main()`.
You can either make the `xe` global (putting it outside the `Main()` method),
or
you can pass it to `notepad()` as an argument.
Like this:

```
//changed it to void cause you arent returning any value
//removed string np argument because you were not using its value (you were overriding it before you use it)
public static void notepad(User u){

  string np = Console.ReadLine();
  u.notepad = np;
}
```

hope it helps.